# What is a good index for my query to get fast results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization, query-performance

I have a query that is pulling form many tables but it is slow and I want to improve it.

```
SELECT 
    ph.phone_call_id AS id,
    ph.call_subject AS callSubject,
    ac.account_name AS accountName,
    ph.trigger_on AS triggerOn,
    ph.isAppointment,
    ph.status,
    ind.name AS industry,
    cc.call_code_name AS callCode,
    ac.account_id FROM phone_calls AS ph
INNER JOIN accounts AS ac ON ph.account_id = ac.account_id
INNER JOIN industries AS ind ON ind.industry_id = ac.industry_id
INNER JOIN call_codes AS cc ON ph.call_code_id = cc.call_code_id
WHERE 
    ac.status = 1 AND 
    ph.status = 1 AND 
    ph.owner_id = 1 AND 
    ac.do_not_call = 0 AND 
    ph.trigger_on BETWEEN '2012-10-09 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-09 23:59:59' 
LIMIT 0,25
```

Note that phone_Calls table has around 4.5 million records and accounts around 300k records.

I have index like this now

```
ph.trigger_on
ph.owner_id
ph.status


ac.status
ac.do_not_call
ac.account_id
```

here is what I get when I explain the query

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that a column that makes a quality index is one that has a high degree of uniqueness. I'm not sure how many `status` values there are in your system, but it is not a good index if there are say only 3 possible statuses for your table.

It would also be helpful to have your indexes be on columns that are central to the join operation you are preforming. In this case `ph.account_id` , `ac.account_id`, `ind.industry_id`, `ac.industry_id`, `ph.call_code_id`, `ph.owner_id` and `cc.call_code_id` all look like good index candidates (if they are not already indexes). Note that if any of your tables has a lot of indexes (over five-ish) this has the potential to slow your queries down. Additionally, if any of your tables involved have a large number of writes or deletes preformed on them (as in comparable to the number of reads) then indexing these tables heavily is unwise because each index file is rewritten much more frequently on tables that have many write operations preformed on them. It has been my experience that indexing is an art form more than science so you'll have to do some experimentation to find what is best for your system. Experiment offline if possible to see what gives the best boost given your dataset. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the info. status is 0,1,2 however I use it in my where clause almost always. Yes I have a lot of indexes and thats why I am asking for help because I don't think I am doing the indexing part correctly.  so for the above query what will be a good index? if I add ph.account_id, ph.call_code_id, and ph.owner_id thats 3 indexes right there so I am not sure what will be the best way to manage those indexes

Comment: I'm not familiar with your dataset, so I can't be sure. Selecting columns that are pretty unique is almost always a good bet. It sounds like you'll have to programatically apply each new index and then run your explain statement. This will reveal which will help the most. Each one should help at least a little, but you want to select the ones that are most relevant. The ones referenced in your join syntax seem like the best bet.

Comment: How can I programably apply each index?

Comment: Add a index like followed: `CREATE INDEX your_index_name ON your_table (column_to_index);` explain your query again and check for improvments,  then drop that index as followed `DROP INDEX your_index_name ON your_table;` and repeat for each index you wish to add.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have mentioned, if your INDEX columns are all 0 and 1 bits, then you don't need an index on that and an id auto-increment should work better for the primary index. I'm guessing phone_call_id is INT and unique? Is this an auto-increment field?

MySQL uses the auto-increment id index internally, so for tables such as this it's a good idea to have it.

If you post your schema structure with SHOW CREATE TABLE accounts; SHOW CREATE TABLE phone_calls; etc we can help you more.

I would take the database - since it's only 300k - and load it locally, then add the auto-increment column if it's not phone_call_id, delete all the other indexes EXCEPT: phone_call_id, account_id, industry_id and call_code_id.

To help you more, I need to know what those other table's structure is, especially how wide and number of rows.